# Is this exercise on forcing trivial?

Tags: logic, set-theory, forcing

I'm reading Nik Weaver's Forcing for Mathematicians. This is one of the exercises.

> Let $P$ be a forcing notion, let $G$ be a generic ideal of $P$, and suppose $G \in \mathbf{M}$. (As we noted at the beginning of the chapter, this can only happen if $P$ is trivial.) Prove that $\mathbf{M}[G] = \mathbf{M}$.

Note that $\mathbf{M}$ is a countable transitive model of ZFC. Also, that $\mathbf{M} \subseteq \mathbf{M}[G]$ in general is proven in the book, so only the other direction remains.

I went on to prove that $g_1 := \bigcup G$ was an element of $G$, so there existed an element that was the extension of every other element. This gives

$$\tau^G = \{\sigma^G; \sigma \in \tau^{-1}(G)\} = \{\sigma^G; \sigma \in \tau^{-1}(g_1)\}$$

for all $P$-names $\tau$. I'm not exactly sure how I should finish. I think a simple induction on name rank should work: first note that $\tau \in \mathbf{M}$ by definition, then take the definable subset of all ordered pairs such that the second element is $g_1$ and then take the function mapping this subset to the set of all first elements of these pairs. With that I basically get that $\{\sigma; \sigma \in \tau^{-1}(G)\} \in \mathbf{M}$. After that, I just map $\sigma$ to $\sigma^G$ (this *is* a function of $\mathbf{M}$ by inductive hypothesis, right?) and I have that $\tau^G \in \mathbf{M}$.

But then I realized that all of this could have been done without defining $g_1$ and just working with $G$ directly. It should still work okay, as $G$ is an element of $\mathbf{M}$. Then I'm done. But I didn't use the fact that $P$ is trivial at all here, so I'm confused.

Also, I invoke quite a few of the axioms of ZFC. I assume a similar result has to hold in some weaker systems. For example, doesn't a similar result hold in ZFC without the replacement axiom? My proof uses it a lot, so I'm not sure. Please let me know if I made a big mistake somewhere here.

Comment: You used the fact that $P$ is trivial since a $P$-generic filter belongs to the ground model only when $P$ is trivial, and you proved $M[G]=M$ from $G\in M$. (Also, your proof looks correct.)

Comment: @HanulJeon Thank you. I do know from the book that $P$ is trivial iff $G$ is in $\mathbf{M}$, so I know that that's not necessarily an issue by itself. It was just really weird to me that Weaver explicitly mentioned that fact in the problem if it wasn't useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Weaver's notation so I checked the book, but still don't understand why $g_1$ must be an element of $G$. Anyway, as you say we don't really need $g_1$. The logic is this, when doing forcing we fix a countable transitive ground model $\mathbf{M}$, choose some generic ideal $G$, and form the extension $\mathbf{M}[G]$ using the name evaluation map $\sigma\mapsto\sigma^G$; this is carried out in $V$, the ambient universe, or the "real world". But if $G\in\mathbf{M}$, then we can also evaluate names in $\mathbf{M}$, and by absoluteness the result is the same as in $V$, so $\mathbf{M}[G]\subseteq\mathbf{M}$.

The whole machinary of forcing (not just this particular result) does go over systems much weaker than ZFC. However, the map $\sigma\mapsto\sigma^G$ is defined by transfinite recursion, for which you want at least some amount of replacement. Kripke-Platek set theory is more than enough; I believe it even works over many subsystems of second-order arithmetic.

Comment: Thank you. It seems like I made a mistake in my proof by assuming that $\bigcup G \in P$. So I guess it's not generally in $G$ either. Thanks for the intuitive explanation!